# something wrong in codename1.ext.codescan cn1lib for iOS

Tags: ios, build, codenameone

When I am sending iOS build with new Codename One Scanner library (I varify import statement and its import com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner;)

then I am getting following error generated on server and iOS build is failed.

`In file included from /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build8058354584873816611xxx/dist/StockTake-src/com_codename1_ext_codescan_NativeCodeScannerImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build8058354584873816611xxx/dist/StockTake-src/ScanCodeImplExt.h:13:
/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build8058354584873816611xxx/dist/StockTake-src/CVZBarReaderViewControllerExt.h:3:9: fatal error: 'ZBarReaderViewControllerExt.h' file not found`

`** BUILD FAILED **`

`The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/StockTake.build/Release-iphoneos/StockTake.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_ext_codescan_NativeCodeScannerImpl.o StockTake-src/com_codename1_ext_codescan_NativeCodeScannerImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)`

its working for android, only iOS is having issue.

-----Edit-----

I have downloaded .cn1lib from the link provided in installation step on https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan and I downloaded it today again to check latest.

Comment: 'ZBarReaderViewControllerExt.h' file not found

Comment: thanks picciano, but the error is from library and that errored library is distributed on server that will cause other CN1 developer to face this issue as well. So I am just waiting for probably @Shai Almog so he can update library link on server.
Cheers mate!

Comment: Can you look in `lib/impl/native/ios` and see if the file is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I forgot to upload the lastest build after fixing this same issue back in December.  I have rebuilt with latest sources and uploaded the cn1lib.  Try downloading again.  Should work now.